# How to avoid HTML text from breaking when inserted in input's value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to replace my hidden input's value with some html text and send it to the server as plain text. Here's how I did :

```
$('#div').append("<input type="hidden" value='<div><h1>Some text</h1><svg ...></svg></div>'");
```

The problem is that the code breaks and displays the value of the input as HTML tags into my template, which makes it unusable to the backend when sent.

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lindow/9p77afc3/2/, while inspecting you'll see that the svg got out of the input's value, that's what I'm trying to avoid.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `input` element is not hidden. Provide it with the `type="hidden"` attribute.

After you added that to your question you have a problem with not escaping quotes. Escape those inner double quotes with backslash, or use single quotes:

```
$('#div').append("<input type='hidden' value='<div><h1>Some text</h1><svg ...></svg></div>'");
```

After the next edit, which added the fiddle, it shows you have single quotes in the `svg` content, and that you do not quote the `value` property's value.

Do it like this:

```
$('.elements').append("<div>hey : <input hidden value=\"" + "<svg ... </svg>" + "\"</div>");
//                                                    ^^                         ^^
```

Corrected fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9p77afc3/4/

Comment: Oh sorry this doesn't answer my question I'll edit it right away, check edit I changed it a bit

Comment: Updated to align with your question. Wow, you really keep updating your question!?

Comment: The issue is not about being hidden, I'll try to replicate the issue on jsfiddle and update

Comment: After your edit, the problem is now with the quotes.

Comment: Yes sorry, if you watch the jsfiddle you'll see while inspecting that the svg got out of the value of the input, that's what I was trying to avoid

Comment: See update to my answer. You did not quote the value.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change single quotes instead of double quotes. 
Try below:

```
$('#div').append("<input type='hidden' value='<div><h1>Some text</h1><svg ...></svg></div>'");
```